# How should I go about method chaining in TypeScript (like how Tiptap does it)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[Tiptap](https://tiptap.dev/) (and many other text editors based on [ProseMirror](https://prosemirror.net/)) has this amazing API where we can chain commands.

For [example](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/5144a6cd1b12a161b5879efab22d2dda0c2a20ba/demos/src/Examples/Default/React/index.jsx#L20):

```js
editor.chain().focus().toggleItalic().run()
```

Here, calling `chain()` returns all the **chainable commands** which themselves return **chainable commands** and that's how the chain goes on and on until you call `run()`.

After calling `run()`, the commands between `chain()` and `run()` are executed in sync.

What's interesting (as far as my knowledge goes) is that this isn't a class.
All of this can also be extended (including typings) by creating custom extensions for Tiptap. See this [bold extension](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/5144a6cd1b12a161b5879efab22d2dda0c2a20ba/packages/extension-bold/src/bold.ts#L65) and its [types](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/5144a6cd1b12a161b5879efab22d2dda0c2a20ba/packages/extension-bold/src/bold.ts#L12).

I did go thru there [source](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/5144a6cd1b12a161b5879efab22d2dda0c2a20ba/packages/core/src/CommandManager.ts#L68) but wasn't able to comprehend much.

I really liked this design pattern and was wondering how should I go about implementing this in general...

Say, I wanted to implement a calculator on this pattern. How can I make this line work?

```js
calculator.chain().setValue(10).add(3).sub(12).run() // 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: In pure javascript (as long as your target device's javascript engine supports it), if you want to chain calls to functions, you could use promises et chain them with ".then()", doc here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @wiwi No, you should not use promises for chaining functions to each other.

Comment: "*What's interesting is that this isn't a class*" - what's so special about a class? Would you know how to do this with classes? It's just that each method is returning an object which conforms to that `ChainedCommands` interface.

Comment: @Bergi I would really like to have an explanation on the reason why you should not use promises for chaining calls

Comment: @wiwi Because promises are used to chain asynchronous actions. Not arbitrary function calls. And a `.then(…).then(…).then(…)` chain is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Bergi in theory I agree with your first statement. I just think that practically speaking promises are usable this way to achieve the OP's purpose (as the API is already there), without going into building some framework API from scratch. Unless that's what he really wants

Comment: @Bergi
I saw this example that extended prototype and worked but they created an instance with the `new` keyword. 

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways you could potentially implement this, here is just one with a simple object. A class encapsulation would propbably be a good idea. So long as you keep your methods contained within a single object, you can keep returning it and adding to the callback queue, which will eventually be executed on `.run()` and break the loop.

```
const calculator = {
  state: { value: 0 },
  callbacks: [] as ((...args: any[]) => any)[],
  _exec: {
    setValue: (val: number) => (calculator.state.value = val),
    add: (val: number) => (calculator.state.value += val),
    sub: (val: number) => (calculator.state.value -= val),
  },
  _queue: {
    setValue: (val: number) => {
      calculator.callbacks.push(() => calculator._exec.setValue(val));
      return calculator._queue;
    },
    add: (val: number) => {
      calculator.callbacks.push(() => calculator._exec.add(val));
      return calculator._queue;
    },
    sub: (val: number) => {
      calculator.callbacks.push(() => calculator._exec.sub(val));
      return calculator._queue;
    },
    run: () => {
      calculator.callbacks.forEach((cb) => cb());
      calculator.callbacks = [];
    },
  },
  chain: () => calculator._queue,
};

calculator.chain().setValue(10).add(3).sub(12).run();
console.log(calculator.state.value); // logs 1
```

Comment: This is a good starting point for me! I was thinking what would happen if I call the `chain()...` at multiple locations.

But then again in a sync environment, they won't affect each other since one will run after the other. Is there a way we can scope callbacks to the chain and not the calculator?

Accepting this answer! :)

Comment: Do you mean that each instance of `chain` should have its own state and callback queue?

Comment: Yes, so that we can also do async.

Comment: That global `callback` queue is a quite overcomplicated design and does not allow for multiple independent chains. No loop should be necessary. This is not a good way to implement method chaining.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `class`:

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  run() { return this.value; }
  add(x) { return new Calculator(this.value + x); }
  sub(x) { return new Calculator(this.value - x); }
  log() { console.log(this.value); return this; }
  static withValue(v) { return new this(v); }
}
const calc = Calculator.withValue(10).add(3).log();
console.log(calc.sub(12).run());
console.log(calc.add(29).run());
```

The only thing that is important for method chaining is to return an object with all the methods (here: a `Calculator` instance) from each of the chainable methods. You can achieve the same without `class` syntax as well:

```js
function calculatorWithValue(v) {
  return {
    run() { return v; },
    add(x) { return calculatorWithValue(v + x); },
    sub(x) { return calculatorWithValue(v - x); },
    log() { console.log(v); return this; },
  };
}
const calc = calculatorWithValue(10).add(3).log();
console.log(calc.sub(12).run());
console.log(calc.add(29).run());
```

I recommend to keep the objects immutable, to allow creation of multiple independent chains or forking of an existing chain - see the examples above, where the second result is `10 + 3 + 29`, not `10 + 3 - 12 + 29`.

If you want the execution to be lazy, that's easy as well:

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(run) {
    this.run = run;
  }
  static withValue(v) { return new this(() => v); }
  add(x) { return new Calculator(() => this.run() + x); }
  sub(x) { return new Calculator(() => this.run() - x); }
  log() { return new Calculator(() => {
    const v = this.run();
    console.log(v);
    return v;
  }); }
}
const calc = Calculator.withValue(10).add(3).log();
console.log(calc.sub(12).run());
console.log(calc.add(29).run());
```

If you want to make this extensible with some kind of plugin architecture, just put more methods on the prototype, or build the object dynamically. For TypeScript, you'd use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to amend the `Calculator` interface with the signatures that your plugin provides.